# Should I expose a "computed" value as a property or a method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class-design, methods, properties

I have a C# class that represents a content type in a web content management system.

We have a field that allows a web content editor to enter an HTML template for how the object is displayed.  It basically uses the handlebars syntax for substituting object property values into the HTML string:

```
<h1>{{Title}}</h1><p>{{Message}}</p>
```

From a class design perspective, should I expose the formatted HTML string (with substitution) as a *property* or *method*?

**Example as property:**

```
public class Example
{
  private string _template;
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
  public string Html 
  {
    get
    {
      return this.ToHtml();
    }
    protected set { }
  }

  public Example(Content content)
  {
    this.Title = content.GetValue("title") as string;
    this.Message = content.GetValue("message") as string;
    _template = content.GetValue("template") as string;
  }

  private string ToHtml()
  {
    // Perform substitution and return formatted string.
  }  
}
```

**Example as method:**

```
public class Example
{
  private string _template;
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }

  public Example(Content content)
  {
    this.Title = content.GetValue("title") as string;
    this.Message = content.GetValue("message") as string;
    _template = content.GetValue("template") as string;
  }

  public string ToHtml()
  {
    // Perform substitution and return formatted string.
  }  
}
```

I'm not sure from a design standpoint does it make a difference or are there reasons why one approach is better than the other?

Comment: The advantage of properties, they are serialized in XML or JSOn, but thats it I think.

Comment: Properties should represent state information. Doesn't matter if they are computed or not. It makes it easier to use them in expressions. Only you know if HTML represents a state of the object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in May 2014](http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/19/when-should-i-write-a-property/). Thanks for the great question!

---

To add to [Robert Harvey's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/233214/31260): a property should be:

- logically a *property* of the class, the way that say its color or year or model are the properties of a car.
- not more than, let's say, ten times slower to compute than fetching from a field.
- something you don't mind being computed while debugging. The VS debugger automatically computes properties.
- unable to fail. Getters should always return a value no matter what the state of the object is.

I don't think your proposed `Html` property hits *any* of those.  Don't make it a property unless it hits *all* of them.

Comment: "unable to fail. Getters should always return a value no matter what the state of the object is."  Shouldn't properties throw an exception after their object has been disposed?

Answer (score 9):

`ToHtml` is correctly a method, as you have written it in both cases.  Just expose it publicly.

Knerd makes a good point: properties can be serialized.  You would never deserialize from the HTML, so it doesn't make much sense to make it a property from that perspective.

Consistent with the way ORM's and repository objects work: fields in a record or tuple are represented with properties, but you retrieve the record (or *some form* of it) using a method.